# types of byte data used in read method in fileinputstream

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I have read about `FileInputStream` and I found that it have read method where it will read the byte data of the file.

What I want to know is what types of byte data does it read? Meaning does it use ASCII or Unicode or any other types?

Comment: It justs reads byte, whatever it is. For your case, you should use StreamReader class. You can specify the encoding in the constructor. When it reads a byte it converts them to Unicode using the specified scheme and puts them back using the same scheme during a write operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what i want to know is what types of byte data does it read? meaning does it use ASCII or Unicode or any other types?

As far as `FileInputStream` and its methods are concerned, there is only one "type" of data.  And that type is "a sequence of bytes (or octets)".

Any other "types" are for another library (or application code) layer to deal with.

The "types" you refer to as ASCII and Unicode are character encodings (roughly speaking).  (In fact, Unicode is NOT an encoding at all ... and doesn't exactly make sense in this context.  Encodings for Unicode have names like "UTF-8" and "UTF-16" and so on - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings.)

Anyway, the standard way to "deal" with text file types (i.e. sequences of characters in some standard character encoding scheme) is to use a `Reader` class.  And there is a wrapper class called `InputStreamReader` that is specifically designed for reading character data from an `InputStream`.

Other non-textual "types" of data are handled by classes like `ZipInputStream`, `InflaterInputStream`, `GZIPInputStream`, the image reader classes, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

ASCII, Unicode, ... apply in case of characters, not bytes. They are just bytes (8 bits).

You can use [`public InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) where you specify the character set.

Answer (score 1):

`FileInputStream` is a binary I/O class. Its the Text I/O that requires conversion from Unicode to a file specific encoding or vice versa but binary I/O does not require any conversion. When you read a byte from a file, the original byte is returned.

Answer (score 0):

**It doesn't change the file encoding.** If you want to decode in the byte[] in a desired encoding, you may use `charset` to convert in desired charset as below:

```
   Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); // breaks too
   String convertedString= new String(byteArray, cs);
```